# How do I do If Post Meta DOES NOT exist?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<?php $buycheck = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'buy-link', true); ?>

            <?php if ( $buycheck ) : ?>
                <div class="section-title sidebar span5">
                    <h5>Get This Release</h5>
                </div>

            <?php else : ?>

                <div class="section-title sidebar span5">
                    <h5>More Releases</h5>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Later in my code I want to be able to say that if buy-link does not exist - i.e. there is no data in that field - then do something, else do something different.

Not sure how to do this! Help appreciated!

(By the way, I posted this question to Wordpress Stack Exchange first. It was voted closed there because it apparently concerns PHP boolean logic more than Wordpress - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60387/how-do-i-do-if-post-meta-does-not-exist#comment78412_60387)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if($buycheck ==''){ /*stuff*/ } ?>
```

this will render $buycheck, and if it is empty **==** is equal to **''** nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a global variable that you can check later to see if the buylink exists:

```
<?php

$buycheck = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'buy-link', true);
$GLOBALS['buy_link_exists'] = !empty($buycheck);

?>

<?php if ( $buycheck ) : ?>
<div class="section-title sidebar span5">
    <h5>Get This Release</h5>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<div class="section-title sidebar span5">
    <h5>More Releases</h5>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Then later on in your code:

```
<?php if ($GLOBALS['buy_link_exists'])): ?>
    it exists, do one thing
<?php else: ?>
    it does not exist, do something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you need the actual value, you can set a global containing the return value from `get_post_meta` so you can use the actual value.

Comment: Thanks @drew010, this is a great answer, very helpful. Not marked as solved as it wasn't exactly on the lines of what I was looking for but I'm very grateful as it was clear and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the vote anyway, I didn't notice you were passing the `$single` parameter at first so I thought it was returning an array.  What you had seemed like good code so I thought you meant you wanted to use the same post meta later and needed a reference to it.  Anyway, good luck with the coding.